# Percentage chart CSS3 animation, starting on view, after scrolling, and not on the page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I am having an issue with a circle animation. The CSS animation works fine, but I cannot get it work on view of the element instead of the load of the all page.

I have gone through many questions on stackoverflow but cannot get this work anyways, I am not sure what is wrong exactly, but when i call the animation class ".slice-right" nothing happens, however, if the class is just inserted in the HTML all is good.

Also the console of the broweser does not show errors.

Can anyone make this work?

Thanks a lot.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="charts.css">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="charts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="xc-one-chart">
<h1>
    hello
</h1><div class="pie">
<div class= "right"></div>

<div class="percent">
    <div class="number">100%</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

***css***

```
.content{
 height:0px
 }
.pie {
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
background-color:transparent;
font-size: 7em;
text-align: center;
border-radius:50%;
 }

.right {
position: absolute;
z-index: 11;
background-color: #ff5252;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
clip: rect(0, 0.5em, 0.5em, 0.5em);
border-radius:50%;

 }


 .percent {
position: absolute;
z-index: 20;
top: 3px;
right: 3px;
bottom: 3px;
left: 3px;
background: #1d2225;
border-radius:50%;
}


.number {
position: absolute;
z-index: 30;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 50%;
line-height: 0;
font-size: .3em;
color:white;
 }

.slice-right{
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
-webkit-animation-name: right-slice;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
 }


@-webkit-keyframes right-slice {
from {
    clip: rect(0, 50%, 0.5em, 0.5em);
}

50% {
    clip: rect(0, 1em, 0.5em, 0.5em);
}

to {
    clip: rect(0, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
}
}
```

***JavaScript***

```
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
var $elem = $(elem);

// Get the scroll position of the page.
var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != 
-1) ? 'body' : 'html');
var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

// Get the position of the element on the page.
var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
var $elem = $('.pie .right');

// If the animation has already been started
if ($elem.hasClass('slice-right')) return;

if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
    // Start the animation
    $elem.addClass('slice-right');
}
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function(){
checkAnimation();
 });
```

Comment: If I add a couple line breaks to allow me to scroll, this code works fine for me. However, in the current state I cannot scroll and so the class is never applied. Changing scroll to ready causes the animation to be played just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/ekgugx76/1/

Comment: No problems :) I will post it as an answer in a minute

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is because there is **no where to scroll**, so the **scroll event is not being triggered**. Adding some space so that you can scroll makes the code work.

```
.content{
 height:500px /*add space*/
 }
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ekgugx76/1/